# How can I show a file count in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I need to manage large numbers of text files, so I need to be able to tell how many files are in a folder when I select it. Currently, in Windows Explorer, I have to right-click to open the folder's properties.

Is there a way to have Explorer show a count of the files in a folder?

It seems there are numerous [alternatives to Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/223843/windows-explore-alternative-for-windows-7-file-browser-like-xp) and a [list of file managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers), but I have no way of knowing which one is best without trialling them all.

Comment: Actually there is this feature in Windows Explorer. Organise -> Folder and Search options -> View -> Display file size information in folder tips

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and I already have this enabled. it gives the total size of files in the folder, and the first few filenames when you mouse hover over the folder, but what it doesn't do is to give the integer quantity of files in the folder.

Comment: This seems to be related: https://superuser.com/questions/470115/how-do-i-display-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-in-windows-explorer — and this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/file-count-not-working-in-windows-7-explorer/bd04f0bb-16f8-4867-861d-6c38a8f8a377

Comment: I does on my computer. When I open the folder I get a total number of files present at the bottom bar

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a way to have Explorer show a count of the files in a folder?

> I need to be able to tell how many files are in a folder when I select it.

The number of files is shown in the Status Bar when a folder is selected.

To turn on the status bar:

- Menu Bar > View > Status Bar

[image]

Comment: This shows the count only when selecting an individual folder… my assumption is that the OP wants to compare folders side-by-side. I've been looking for a similar feature. Tried enabling the *File count* column in the *Details* view, but that just stays empty.

Comment: @slhck The question says "I need to be able to tell how many files are in a folder **when I select it.**"

Comment: Ah, true that, guess I was adding my own problem on top of the OP's :)

Comment: Also works with a selection. So you can select all .txt files and it will show that total in the status bar too.

Comment: @slhck maybe what you are looking for is _Beyond Compare_ that does a folder or file comparison, or _WinSCP_

Comment: @slhck XYPlorer *almost* does what you want. You can display 2 windows (tabs) side by side. The number of files in the selected tab is shown in the status bar. You do have to switch tabs to compare the numbers.

Comment: The count at the bottom is useful, but it does mean you have to navigate into each folder. I suppose my dream tool would have columns for folder contents, in the same way you get columns for file size etc for individual files. I have beyond compare which is a very good tool but I couldn't see a way to get folder summaries.

Comment: @SolarBrian That's what you asked for "I need to be able to tell how many files are in a folder **when I select it.**"

Comment: ok, I take your point, but then what explorer gives when you select a folder is the 'number of items' ie files and subfolders in the immediate branch, whereas I'm looking to find the total number of files as you'd get if you right clicked to properties, which I also mention in the OP.

Comment: @SolarBrian It's much easier to do this with a batch file ...